# Mensagem de aviso ao juntar ano, mês e dia com a função ymd() do lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

Estou praticando com o pacote `hflights`

Instalo o pacote;

Carrego o pacote; e

Carrego o lubridate

```
install.packages("hflights")
library(hflights)
library(lubridate)
```

Os dados (`Year`, `Month`, `DayofMonth`) vem separados e gostaria de junta-los.

Para tanto, combinei a função `ymd()` do `lubridate` junto com a funçao `paste0` do `base`, da seguinte forma:

```
hflights %>% 
  mutate(dt=ymd(paste0(Year, "0", Month, DayofMonth))) %>% 
  select(dt) %>% 
  head()
```

Aparentemente, funcionou:

```
   dt
1 2011-01-01
2 2011-01-02
3 2011-01-03
4 2011-01-04
5 2011-01-05
6 2011-01-06
Warning message:
 39539 failed to parse.
```

Acontece que o resultado veio acompanhada da mensagem

```
Warning message:
 39539 failed to parse.
```

Sei que isso não significa erro, mas sim uma mensagem de aviso.
Só não consegui identificar o que esse aviso significa.
O **R** falhou em analisar o quê, mais precisamente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta mudar o `paste0` para `paste` com o argumento `sep = "-"`.

```
library(hflights)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

hflights %>% 
  mutate(dt = ymd(paste(Year, Month, DayofMonth, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  select(dt) %>% 
  head()
#          dt
#1 2011-01-01
#2 2011-01-02
#3 2011-01-03
#4 2011-01-04
#5 2011-01-05
#6 2011-01-06
```

Apesar de o pacote `lubridate` ser muito útil, neste caso não é preciso carregá-lo, a função base `as.Date` chega para resolver o problema.

```
library(hflights)
library(dplyr)

hflights %>% 
  mutate(dt = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, DayofMonth, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  select(dt) %>% 
  head()
#          dt
#1 2011-01-01
#2 2011-01-02
#3 2011-01-03
#4 2011-01-04
#5 2011-01-05
#6 2011-01-06
```